# Issue installing Xdeug: undefined symbol: sapi_globals

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, redhat

I'm having an issue installing Xdebug on a Redhat server with Php 5.4.14 installed. This server does not have ports open to access the internet, so I have build Xdebug from the source following the guide provided on the install page and then by the wizard.

After adding the `zend_extension="my/path/to/xdebug.so"` and restarting Apache, I am greeted with the following message in the Apache system error logs:

`/modules/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20100525/xdebug.so:  /apps/Apache/httpd-2.4.4/modules/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20100525/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: sapi_globals`

After googling this there isn't a clear way to fix this, so I came here :).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.